# Finding good wireless earphones with ear-hooks and a connecting cable

Tags: audio, headphones, earphones, audio-quality

Over the years, I've come to settle on a particular style of earphone. They look like this:

[image: Earphones]

The key features are that they are wireless, have a hook that goes over the ear, have soft tips that go into the ear, and have a cable connecting the two earpieces. They also need to have voice assistant support (requiring a mic) and normal music controls (volume, skip). This design lets me pop the earphones out and allow them to hang from the ear-hooks, or to take them off my ears and let them hang around my neck by the cable.

Here's the problem: designs like this tend to be fairly cheep and unreliable, and worst of all, hard to replace. My Amazon cart shows I buy a new pair about once a year, because the old one tends to die. That's not horrible by itself, I guess, because they're pretty inexpensive to buy. The real issue is I can never buy the same pair more than once or twice. By the time one pair dies, that particular brand/company has seemingly disappeared, the listing on Amazon is no longer available, and I need to find a look-alike pair.

Well, the other week my last pair died, and the replacements I got sounded awful.

So here's what I need your help with. I have gotten really great sound out of this design in the past, but I need to find a way to get headphones like this without risking getting something that sounds like I'm listening through a tin can.

There are three potential avenues I'm looking for:

1. **A reliable, well-reviewed brand that makes this kind of earphone.** If I can find this, and I like it, then I have a shot at getting a lasting pair of these things, or at least the ability to reliably replace them.
2. **Some info on the generic model that all these companies are using.** I'm fairly sure that all these brands that come and go are just buying the same design (or handful of designs) from wherever they're made (China), slapping a label on it and calling it a day. They all have the same robot voice saying the "power on" and "power off" messages. If I can find the specs of the generic model(s), maybe I can compare the actual speakers inside them to tell if one will suck or not.
3. **Some way to tell if a pair will suck (sound-wise)**. This ties in with the last approach, but really I'd just like any method of looking at a listing and judging the quality of the sound. Obviously every listing has a bunch of marketing garbage, which is why I was thinking of looking into the generic listings, but if there is any particular spec I can look for on a listing, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Comment: A disqualified product would be bone conduction versions?

Comment: Yeah. Those might be good, but I've never really used them. I'd be willing to look into them if I really couldn't find anything else, but they don't really fit what I'm asking for here.